# error spawn E2BIG in webpack when process.env.VARNAME is large

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, environment-variables

I have `gulpfile` which uses `webpack-stream` for running Webpack. I also have this code in gulpfile which is run before webpack:

```js
const json = require('./config.json');
process.env.DATA = JSON.stringify(json);
```

The problem is that when this `json` is really big, gulp script results in this error:

```
Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error in plugin "webpack-stream"
Message:
    spawn E2BIG
Details:
    errno: E2BIG
    code: E2BIG
    syscall: spawn
```

What should I do? I need this `process.env.DATA` for [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) and [webpack-conditional-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-conditional-loader).

Answer (score 0):

I moved this code from `gulpfile` to `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
const json = require('./config.json');
```

And now inside `plugins` option of webpack, I have:

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.DATA': JSON.stringify(json),
  }),
],
```

This fixed the error but made the `webpack-conditional-loader` stop working. I haven't fixed that yet but the issue's fixed.

#### Update

`webpack-conditional-loader` doesn't work anyway! I couldn't use it. So I used [ifdef-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifdef-loader) and it works.